# AnimatePresence show both elements when animating

Tags: reactjs, animation, framer-motion

I am to make a step-like animation, hence, when I click a button, another `div` than the previous is shown, e.g:

```
import { motion, AnimatePresence } from 'framer-motion'

const MyApp= props => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  return (
    <>
      <AnimatePresence>
        {count == 0 && (
          <motion.div
            transition={{ duration: 2 }}
            initial={{ opacity: 1 }}
            animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
            exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
          >
            Hello 1
            <button onClick={() => { setCount(count + 1) }}
          </motion.div>
        )}
      </AnimatePresence>
      <AnimatePresence>
        {count == 1 && (
          <motion.div
            transition={{ duration: 2 }}
            initial={{ opacity: 1 }}
            animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
            exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
          >
            Hello 2
            <button onClick={() => { setCount(count + 1) }}
          </motion.div>
        )}
      </AnimatePresence>
    </>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

However, the issue is, that when one `div` is fading out/in, the other is also fading in/out, hence, I have two elements at the same time. Instead I thought it would just animate one, remove it, and animate the other.

Am I doing something wrong here ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Since you want to animate them together they should be under one `<AnimatePresence />`
2. AnimatePresence requires you to add an explicit key on the component you are animating beneath it so that it can track the components as they are added and removed https://www.framer.com/api/motion/animate-presence/#unmount-animations
3. Since you want to replace one component with another you need to add the prop `exitBeforeEnter` on the `AnimatePrensence`. https://www.framer.com/api/motion/animate-presence/#animatepresenceprops.exitbeforeenter

```
        <AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter> // Note on #3
          {isGreenBox ? (// Note on #1
            <GreenBox
              initial={{ scale: 0 }}
              animate={{ scale: 1 }}
              exit={{ scale: 0 }}
              key="green" // Note on #2
            />
          ) : (
            <PurpleBox
              initial={{ scale: 0 }}
              animate={{ scale: 1 }}
              exit={{ scale: 0 }}
              key="purple" // Note on #2
            />
          )}
        </AnimatePresence>
```

Here is a working example I created :) https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-animation-presence-exitbeforeenter-0miq0